# Gaussian smoothing in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing

For an `m` x `n` array of elements with some noisy images, I want to perform [Gaussian smoothing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_blur). How do I do that in [MATLAB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MATLAB)?

I've read the math involves smoothing everything with a kernel at a certain scale, but I have no idea how to do this in MATLAB.

Comment: You should accept the top answer if you think it solved your problem (which certainly seems to be the case). To do that just click on the check mark next to the answer. Welcome to the community :)

Answer (score 28):

Hopefully, you have the Image Processing toolbox. If so, then you can create a Gaussian filter with the [fspecial function](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/images/fspecial.html) like so:

```
myfilter = fspecial('gaussian',[3 3], 0.5);
```

I have used the default values for hsize ([3 3]) and sigma (0.5) here, but you might want to play around with them. hsize is just the size of the filter, in this case it is a 3 x 3 matrix. Sigma is the sigma of the gaussian function (see the bottom of the fspecial function page).

Now you can use [imfilter](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/images/imfilter.html) to filter your image:

```
myfilteredimage = imfilter(unfilteredimage, myfilter, 'replicate');
```

here I have simply passed in the unfilteredimage, the filter, and a parameter that says how the filter should handle the boundaries. In this case, I've chosen replicate which sets input array values outside the bounds of the array to the nearest array border value, but you can try some other values (or leaving off that option sets all outside of image values to 0).