# What is the reason behind parameter "truncate" in scipy.ndimage.gaussian_filter1d

Tags: python, scipy, gaussian, data-processing, gaussianblur

everyone.

I'm gone through a lot of documentation, website, however, I still don't understand "What is the reason behind parameter "truncate" in `scipy.ndimage.gaussian_filter1d`"

Below is the description taken from scipy doc,
`scipy.ndimage.gaussian_filter(input, sigma, order=0, output=None, mode='reflect', cval=0.0, truncate=4.0)`

As I went through the code, width of the window is defined as following,
`width = 2*int(truncate*sigma + 0.5) + 1`

You can see that the truncate always times with the sigma. Isn't the parameter "sigma" enough? Could someone help me regarding this issue please?

Comment: The answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16165666/how-to-determine-the-window-size-of-a-gaussian-filter) might help you.

Comment: think it is explained clearly [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25216382/gaussian-filter-in-scipy)

Comment: thank you @themiurge. That thread is quite helpful. it almost answers to my question. I did a bit of research further to get all I need.