# How to apply a Gaussian filter with a kernel of size 5 x 5 and apply it on the image by matlab

Tags: image-processing, matlab

I created a filter with a Gaussian kernel of size 5 x 5 such that the center has a meshgrid order .      I want it to apply on an image.  How would I do that?

Comment: Guy named `imfilter` might. At times he is really `fspecial`.

Comment: @Divakar - That made me laugh.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

As @Divakar has already pointed out, you could refer to the imfilter command. Please refer
[Gaussian filter in MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2773606/gaussian-filter-in-matlab).
The sample code is

```
   %%# Read an image
   I = imread('peppers.png');

   %# Create the gaussian filter with hsize = [5 5] and sigma = 2
   %You have created this. so you can actually skip
   G = fspecial('gaussian',[5 5],2);

   %# Filter it
   Ig = imfilter(I,G,'same');
   %# Display
   imshow(Ig)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, but I want to create my own filter of the given size 5 x 5 acts on the image, but I do not know how to do it.

Comment: @m.golzadeh - Now you're saying something completely different than what you told in your comment to me.  Do you want to know how to **create** the Gaussian kernel, or do you just want to know how to generate it?  `fspecial` can be used to calculate the latter.  The former requires a bit more work.  Please update your question with this information so we know what you really want.

Comment: I created a filter using the formula and I want this filter is applied on the image to the specified size. In fact, I do not know how the filter size of 5 x 5 on the image size of 128 x 128 would apply.

Answer (score 1):

As what @Divakar said, use [`imfilter`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imfilter.html).  You've already created the Gaussian kernel using `meshgrid` and using some other calculations.  `imfilter` is called using the following way:

```
out = imfilter(in, f);
```

`in` is the input image, `out` is the output image and `f` is the kernel that is defined by you.  There are filters that are already defined that you can use using [`fspecial`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/fspecial.html).  You could also use the `gaussian` flag from `fspecial` to generate your Gaussian kernel for you, but I'm assuming you're generating this by yourself as an exercise / homework.

With `imfilter` there are other flags you can use, but the above is the most basic way to call it.  There are flags to handle what happens along the border when the kernel goes out of bounds when performing filtering, or if you want to perform convolution or correlation, and so on.  I defer you to the documentation for more details, but the above code is the most basic to get you started.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you so much, but I got the filter causing a Gaussian kernel, combined with the positive and negative lobes formed with a given size
This also creates a filter for the convolution of the input image, but I do not know how I've created a filter that I applied on the input image.

Comment: @m.golzadeh That was not what you said in your question.  You said you have a Gaussian filter and want to apply it to an image... you didn't say you have a filter that **causes / outputs** a Gaussian kernel.  Please **update** your question so that it has **all of the information**.  Your comment also conflicts with your question.  You said in your question that you created a Gaussian kernel, but now you say you don't know how you created it?  Please update your question so that we know all of the facts.

Comment: I created a filter using the formula and I want this filter is applied on the image to the specified size. In fact, I do not know how the filter size of 5 x 5 on the image size of 128 x 128 would apply.

Comment: @m.golzadeh : Use `imfilter`.  The image size and the filter size don't have to be the same.