# How do I detect overlapping almost circular objects in MATLAB?

Tags: algorithm, matlab, image-processing

I'm working on a project which involves detecting the red blood cells in the blood. RBCs in the blood are never perfectly circular (usually almost eliptical) and they often overlap.

I've searched and found a number of algorithms, but most work for circles only. However, in my case it needs to work for blood from patients with sickle cell disease, where the RBCs are elongated or sickle-shaped. For reference [here is an example source image](http://www.sicklecellanaemia.org/OER/article.php?id=66).

Can you suggest an algorithm or approach to solve this problem?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Unfortunately this site does not answer "any help" questions covering whole projects. Your question needs to be narrowed down a lot - into a single technical issue that is clear and can be answered in a straightforward manner. You should start with research into image processing in Matlab. If you have trouble understanding a topic, or implementing it for your project, *then* is a good time to ask a question about it on Stack Overflow.

Comment: If my answer has helped please remember to accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, this question is really too broad to answer completely. However, I can give you some pointers in how to address this.

For starters, get yourself the MATLAB [Image Processing toolbox](http://us.mathworks.com/products/image/).

"Identify red blood cells" is a deceptively simple-sounding task. The first step with any project like this is to figure out what *exactly* you want to achieve, then start breaking it down into steps of how you will achieve that. Finally, there is the experimental-developmental stage where you try and implement your plan (realise what is wrong with it, then try again).

Cell counting normally uses circularity to identify cells, but that's not possible here because you state you want to identify sickle cells. The other main characteristics distinguishing RBCs from other cells is the colour and size. The colour is more absolute, so start with that. Then think about size. [This is a good tutorial on the process of identifying cells](http://pythonvision.org/basic-tutorial/) although it is in Python the principle is the same.

So we have:

1. Apply a filter to your image, either isolating the red channel (RGB) or something more complex. Make it monochrome (we don't need colour data).
2. Smooth the image (e.g. [gaussian filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2771114/gaussian-smoothing-in-matlab)) to reduce the noise and artefacts
3. Find [regional maxima](http://nl.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imregionalmax.html) which are (hopefully!) in the center of cells
4. [Label the regional maxima](http://nl.mathworks.com/help/images/labeling-and-measuring-objects-in-a-binary-image.html) (this should give you the number of cells)
5. [Watershed](http://nl.mathworks.com/help/images/examples/marker-controlled-watershed-segmentation.html) to find the whole cells an measure size

Hopefully that is enough to get you started!

Comment: I've done the first 2 steps, currently working on the 3rd one. But I'm not really sure I understood how finding the regional maxima helps us over here. 

Thanks a lot btw.

Comment: If finding region maxima is to count the total number of cells, isn't it based on the assumption that there's only one maxima per cell?

Comment: Happy to help! The regional maxima approach is making use of an artefact of gaussian blurring: that the regional maxima will be the center of regions in the image. If you find that your image is not uniform enough for this to be the case, you may find it useful to apply a threshold first and turn the image binary (black-white, rather than grey).

Comment: As to the *why* of needing the maxima: it's just a simple way to separate overlapping cells. If we know the middle of each cell, we can classify any region of the image as being associated with one cell or another by distance alone. If this fails on sickle cells there are other options though!